# How to remove Layer in Cocos2d?

Tags: ios, xcode, release, removechild

What is wrong with my code?

```
if(menu){
    [menu removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES]; // 1 line
    [menu removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];   // 2 line
    menu = nil;
}
```

It fails, however if I comment first or second line everything is good. 
BUT if I dont clean childrenNodes, they would not be cleaned, and if I dont clean the menu from parent, it would not release itself.

What should I do?

Comment: I think you may want to take a look at that cleanup bool parameter ;)

Comment: with parameter - YES and NO - all the same =(

Comment: how about removing menu from parent? I guess the parent of the menu is self so it would looks like this [self removeChild:menu cleanup:Yes]

Comment: Thanks for help! The problem was in parent class. I tried to remove one object twice.